# Setting negative marks in an string to zero (java)

Tags: java

Help, i cant figure this out, im new to java and never coded before this class im taking. the assignment is a code that deals with voting, basically the votes are given and i need to formalise them and make sure there are no errors such as negative votes. i dont thing i am suppose to change any of the code that was given including the constructor and the initialiser for each part. i need help with the part that says `//TODO 3`

```
import java.util.*;

public class VotingPaper {
    // the numbers marked on the paper
    private ArrayList<Double> marks;
    // precision required for matching doubles
    private double epsilon = 10e-4;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class VotingPaper.
     * s will be a sequence of doubles, separated by commas.
     * e.g. if s is "1,22,-13,456", marks is set to <1,22,-13,456>.
     * s can also be a sigle value i.e. with no comma
     */
    public VotingPaper(String s) {
        marks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String x : s.split(","))
            marks.add(Double.parseDouble(x));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contents of the paper.
     */
    public ArrayList<Double> getMarks() {
        //TODO 1
        return marks;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the paper has the correct number of marks i.e. one for each candidate.
     * If YES, ensures that the negative marks have been set to zero and
     * that marks are normalized to sum up to 1.0 and then returns true
     * If NO, it returns false
     */
    public boolean isFormal(int noOfCandidates) {
        // TODO 2

        if (noOfCandidates == marks.size()) {
            setNegativeMarksToZero();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets all negative marks to zero
     */
 public void setNegativeMarksToZero()
{
   //TODO 3
   double negativeMark = marks.get(1).doubleValue();
   for (Double val : marks) {
       System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
       if (val.doubleValue() < 0.0) {
           val = Double((double)0.0);
           System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
       }
       else { 
           normalizeMarks();
       }
   }


}

    private void normalizeMarks() {
    }
}
```

This is the code. this is for a project and im stuck, i cant get the string to replace the negative numbers in the string with `0.0` but i can get it to set the negative value as `val.doubleValue()` and set that to `0.0`. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i should addt that the normailize marks at the bottom is to call the next method that i didnt bother including here

Comment: please post code that will at least compile, you are creating a String marks in a for loop over an array or list that is called marks.

Comment: @Stultuske yeah sorry i changed that part  a bit since i first had the problem, the version that compiles properly is this, `public void setNegativeMarksToZero()
    {
       //TODO 3
       double negativeMark = marks.get(1).doubleValue();
       for (Double val : marks) {
           System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
           if (val.doubleValue() < 0.0) {
               val = Double((double)0.0);
               System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
           }
           else { 
               normalizeMarks();
           }
       }


    }`

Comment: @Mr_Sandwich153 - why didn't you just update your question?  Do you not realize that you're able to do that?

Comment: @Steve no this is my first time asking a question here, ill do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I know what you're asking, but if you just want `setNegativeMarksToZero`  to replace negative values in the `marks` list with 0 values, you can do this:

```
public void setNegativeMarksToZero() {
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.size() ; i++) {
        if (marks.get(i) < 0.0)
            marks.set(i, 0.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: or, in a single line: marks.set(i, marks.get(i) > 0.0 ? marks.get(i) : 0.0);

Comment: the Java compiler probably optimizes this so that you're 100% correct, but if not, then @Stultuske, you're alternative can mean unnecessary calls to get() and set() for each mark that is a valid value, which will usually be all of them I expect.